# Encouraging branching in a chilli plant

Tags: branches

I have an indoor chilli plant that is a bit too tall for my liking.

The problem is, for some reason, it is not branching out from the eyes down towards the bottom.

If I cut the tree along the line as shown in the below picture, would that encourage the branching at the eyes shown?

[image: Chilli plant with tall stem, marked with potential trim level]

Comment: It appears to need more light.

Comment: How old is this plant?

Comment: @Bamboo it is 2 years old

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is right by the window so it does get as much light aa possible but my area indeed is mostly cloudy throughout the year. However, my other chilli plants don't have this issue.